# How to handle half ULR in Selenium and to check it has Captcha or not

Tags: python, selenium

I want to check in websites(calling from database) that does it has captcha or not. Now the problem is that for every website the captcha ID, Class, Xpath is different. I want a smater way to check if captcha avaliable or not. if it is avalible store in either in database or in CSV etc. second check currently URLs I have is in this from e.g **google.com** if I gave this to selenium it does not pick this URL. what I understand that it need a complete URL e.g **https://www.google.com** not www is common for all but http and https is different. how can be this solved. now for www I wrote below code. but the rest I'm not able to make Logic

```
db_conn = base_class.table_selected_urls() # data coming from.. 
# ...database
db_conn.execute("SELECT DISTINCT Domain,Site_name FROM URLS_INFO")
urls = db_conn.fetchall() # after that all distinct urls is saving. 
# ...in urls
for url in urls:
    url_name = url[0] # spliting url to add **www.** with it
    url_source = url[1]
    if url_name.split('.')[0] != "www":
        url_name = "www." + url_name
        print(url_name)
```

The data from the database is comming like **[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)** after this code. now how to check that this website is actually http or https. because selenium can't process it

Comment: it looks like the question is missing some code, the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @D.L Sir/Ma'am with due respect. This was having three problem 1) URL without www so the code is gaven for it to solve. 2) Http and Https is different for all URLs. So i don't know how to handel it. 3) once a site open that how to check captcha because for every captcha the ID, Class, Xpath is different. I hope this will help to understand my problem. thank you. hope to hear from you soon with a good solution.

Comment: it doesnt help.  for example, users will need to know what `db_conn` is. At the moment in the question **it is undefined**. presumably it comes from an import. likewise for `url` is **also undefined**....  so people answering the question have to guess what the variables mean which makes it difficult to answer properly.

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @D.L Sir I edit it can you now try it to understand